# Why uninitialized char array is filled with random symbols?

Tags: c++, cuda, char

I have a this fragment of code in **C++**:

```
char x[50];
cout << x << endl;
```

which outputs some random symbols as seen here:
[image]

So my first question: what is the reason behind this output? Shouldn't it be spaces or at least same symbols?

The reason I am concerned with this is that I am writing program in CUDA and I'm doing some character manipulations inside `__global__` function, hence the use of `string` gives a "calling host function is not allowed" error.
But if I am using "big enough" char array (each chunk of text I am operating with differs in size, meaning that it will not always utilize char array fully) it's sometimes not fully filled and I left with junk like in the picture below hanging at the end of text:

[image]

So my second question: is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: what is the reason? - you did not initialize it. Is there any way to avoid this? - Yes, initialize it.

Comment: So is there a short way to initialize it with spaces?

Comment: https://www.google.de/search?q=init+char+array&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=NgRWVsacJorSU4L0vJgL

Comment: `cout << new char[50] << endl;` Huh? You're after leaking memory the hard way?

Comment: @Schizo, Yes, use `std::string` and use the constructor taking a size and fill character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **what is the reason behind this output?**

The values in an automatic variable are **indeterminate**. The standard doesn't specify it, so it might be spaces as you said, it might be random content.

> [...] sometimes not fully filled and I left with junk [...]

Strings in C are null-terminated, so any routine dedicated to printing a string will loop as long as no null byte is encountered. In uninitialized memory, this null byte occurs randomly (or not at all). These weird, trailing characters are a result of that.

> **is there any way to avoid this?**

Yes. Initialize it.

Comment: @Downvoter Reason for downvote? Did I forget anything?

Answer (score 1):

*(will assume x86 in this post)*

> what is the reason behind this output?

Here's roughly what happens, in assembly, when you do `char x[50];`:

```
ADD ESP, 0x34 ; 52 bytes
```

Essentially, the stack is moved up by 0x34 bytes (must be divisible by 4). Then, that space on the stack *becomes* `x`. There's no cleaning, no changes or pushes or pops, just this space becoming `x`. Anything that was there before (abandoned params, return addresses, variables from previous function calls) will be in `x`.

Here's roughly what happens when you do `new char[50]`:

```
1. Control gets passed to the allocator
2. The allocator looks for any heap of sufficient size (readas: an already allocated but uncommited heap)
3. If 2 fails, the allocator makes a new heap
4. The allocator takes the heap (either the found or allocated one) and commits it
5. The address of that heap is returned to your code where it is used as a char*
```

The same as with a stack, you get whatever data is there. Some programs or systems may have allocators that zero out heaps when they are allocated or committed, where others may only zero when allocated but not committed, and some may not zero at all. Depending on the allocator, you may get clean memory or you may get re-used and dirty memory. This is why the values here can be non-zero and aren't predictable.

> is there any way to avoid this?

In the case of heap memory, you can overload the `new` and `delete` operators in C++ and always zero newly allocated memory. You can see examples of overloading these operators [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new). As for memory on the stack, you just have to live with zeroing it out every time.

```
ZeroMemory(myArray, sizeof(myarray));
```

Alternatively, for both methods, you could stay away from naked arrays and use std::vector or other wrappers that take care of initialization for you. You'll still want to make sure to initialize integers and other numeric or pointer data-types, though.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to avoid it. C++ does not initialize automatic variables of built-in types (such as arrays of built-in types in your case) automatically, you need to initialize them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you having issues with this code?

```
char x[50];
cout << new char[50] << endl;
cout << x << endl;
```

You're leaking memory with the 'new char[50] without a corresponding delete.

Also, uninitialized memory is undefined as others have said and in most cases you get garbage within that memory block.  A better method is to initialize it:

```
char x[50] = {};
char* y = new char[50]();
```

Then just remember to call delete on y later to free the memory.  Yes, the OS will do it for you, but this is never a way to write good programs though.

Comment: I understand all the fuss about memory leakage, but that was just demonstration. :) I should've never posted that line with `new` operator...