# Random Symbols Getting Printed Without Initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, symbols

I made a fairly short text-based animation program:

```
#include <iostream>

void animation(char words[], int sizeOfWords) {
    for(int x = 0; x < sizeOfWords; x++){
         for(double y = 0; y < 10000000; y++);
         std::cout << words[x];
         if(words[x] == '!') std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() { 
    char words[] = {'H','e','l','l','o',' ','W','o','r','l','d','!','T','h','i','s',' ','i','s',' ','m','y',' ','f','i','r','s','t',' ','C','+','+',' ','a','n','i','m','a','t','i','o','n','!','H','o','p','e',' ','y','o','u',' ','e','n','j','o','y','e','d','!'};

    int amountOfLetters = 0;
    for(unsigned x : words) amountOfLetters++;

    animation(words, amountOfLetters);
}
```

When I first made the program I forgot to initialize  **int amountOfLetters;** to 0. That is when I got all these random symbols. The program is fine with or without initializing it. Just without assigning 0 to it, I get these extras in the end.

**Without Initialisation Of The Variable** will give the following result:

> Hello World!
>   This is my first C++ animation!
>   Hope you enjoyed!
>   !
>   t ht  ÉH P j     T j ­Ðou2ö¤.■   Á╬ouÈ╬ouht     mzou
>   Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 11.466 s
>   Press any key to continue.

**With Initialisation Of The Variable** will give the following result:

> Hello World!
>   This is my first C++ animation!
>   Hope you enjoyed!
>   Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 4.444 s
>   Press any key to continue.

You could try running the codes yourself if you want. I would just like to know why are these symbols being printed out. If you can help i'd appreciate it. If not thanks for stopping by.

This post isn't a duplicate of **Why uninitialized char array is filled with random symbols?**. I talk about passing the number of elements in an array and passing them as argument, afterwards looping through them. The other post is simply just talking about initializing an array  **Without Information in it**  and printing it. Meanwhile, again, I am talking about  **Having Information**, just the size of the array holding them was the problem. Simply theirs is about printing an array with no elements, mine is about looping through an array with elements but, mistakenly making an error for the size.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why uninitialized char array is filled with random symbols?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33924275/why-uninitialized-char-array-is-filled-with-random-symbols)

Comment: Oh.. I tried looking, couldn't find it. Even when I entered the title it didn't show anything similar. Anyways, i'll read it, thanks.

Comment: I used Google, but don't know if that question answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

> When I first made the program I forgot to initialize int amountOfLetters; to 0. That is when I got all these random symbols. The program is fine with or without initializing it. Just without assigning 0 to it, I get these extras in the end.

That's because without initializing `amountOfLetters` the `amountOfLetters++;` operation is undefined behavior.

`amountOfLetters` may have an arbitrary value at the beginning of the loop, as it was left on the stack from previous operations.

---

Also note that you could greatly simplify and improve your code just omitting the loop and write:

```
 animation(words, sizeof(words));
```

Comment: Thank you for the `animation(words, sizeof(words));` it really helped.             Also, realizing that `amountOfLetters` could start at any random number, and increment from there helps me understand my mistake. It's like `for(int x = 0; x < **some number passed the last index of the array words**; x++){...}`

Answer (score 1):

Your `animation` function is accessing the char array by index, until the index == `sizeOfWords`. If `amountOfLetters` is not initialised you will start incrementing a random value, and will therefore read past the end of the array in `animation`. That, of course, has random values.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I'll take that into consideration next time. Although I doubt I'll do the sizeOfWords consider I can easily do like another comment said `sizeOf(words)`.

Comment: @J.Purcell Use your _new weapon_ carefully though! `sizeof(words)` won't actually work right inside of the `animation()` function.

Comment: Mhm, I noticed that. When working on little problems with my code in the beginning I tried to do something similar to `variable x = sizeof(words)`, and it didn't work. Figured why, now I know. Thanks.

Comment: As mentioned above, `words` decays into a pointer inside a function (in most cases), and `sizeof(words)` won't work. I would recommend that you use an std container - `std::vector` most likely.